# poor ping performance via shell with asyncio

Tags: python, performance, networking, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am working on an application that can monitor many IP addresses in a short time. For this I am using asyncio to launch the pings sequentially while waiting for a response. The problem is that I have detected that when the script validates several IP addresses (for now 1024) there are some that do not respond to ping, but if I do it sequentially yes, it is as if it does not manage to process the amount of ping it receives.

the "run" function is wrapped in asyncio.run(), the script runs 100 tasks at a time by default.

```
def wait_resources(concurrent_tasks=1):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(concurrent_tasks)
    def wrapper(function):
        @wraps(function)
        async def inside_function(*args, **kwargs):
            async with semaphore:
                return await function(*args, **kwargs)
        return inside_function
    return wrapper


@wait_resources(concurrent_tasks=100)
async def asyncping(ip):
    cmd = f'ping -c {PING_COUNT} -i {PING_INTERVAL} -W {PING_TIMEOUT} {ip}'
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    await proc.communicate()
    return not proc.returncode


async def run():
    ips_to_validate = (ip for ip in get_all_ips())
    up_devices = 0
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(asyncping(ip), name=ip) for ip in ips_to_validate
    ]
    for count, task in enumerate(tasks):
        await task
        if task.result():
            up_devices += 1
    print(f'devices: {up_devices}/{count}')
```

When I start the test sequentially, for example, 100 out of 1024 devices respond, but when I run it concurrently with the code above, sometimes 45 devices respond, other times 50 and so on, in the wireshark captures the packets are seen leaving, but no response is seen. I did a test placing a sleep(0.08) to delay the creation of the pings, and it worked, but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong because it seems to me that there aren't many icmp packets generated in a second either.

Does anyone have any suggestions to improve performance?